# Trying to pull data from text boxes on a form into a query and out to a table?

Tags: ms-access

I posted a couple times over the last couple of days about some trouble I'm having with an inventory database that I'm trying to make at work. I have very little experience, so have been mostly following YouTube tutorials and walk throughs online.

Essentially I have a table that will be filled with inventory information such as ID number, manufacturer, model number, etc. I then have a form that has a text box for each field in the table that the user will fill in and then an Add, Delete and Edit button that will allow them to either Add a new record by filling in the text boxes and clicking Add or select a current record in the table from a combo box or list and edit it or delete it by clicking the associated buttons.

I tried to code this first and kept getting an error for the past two days no matter how much I tried to fix it and what advice I got on here, so now I'm at the point where I'm just using queries to do it.

Right now I have a main table, temp table, the form, and then these queries:
1. delete query that will clear the temp table
2. append query that will take the records from my temp table and add them to my main table
3. append query that will take the selected record on form and add it to the temp table
4. update query that will update the fields on the main table to the data in the temp one
5. delete query that will delete the record you select on the main form from the main table

This was my plan:
for adding a new record
1. run query no.1
2. load the form
3. if OK button clicked:
4. run query no.2

for editing
1. run query no.1
2. run query no.3
2. load the form
3. if OK button clicked:
4. run query no.4

for deleting:
1. load a msgbox with the YesNo options
2. if Yes button clicked:
3. run query no.5

The one I'm having trouble with is query number 3. I've made the query correctly to the best of my knowledge, but when I fill out the form and click add it tells me the query is going to append 0 rows and then it doesn't add anything to the temp table.

I also can't seem to figure out how to take the data from the temp table and move it to the main table using the query.

I'm linking to an IMGUR post with screenshots in it here:
[http://imgur.com/a/ffWge](https://imgur.com/a/ffWge)

Any ideas?

Comment: You are making it _way too hard_ for yourself. Bind the form to the table and you can skip all the query stuff and code. That's the magic of Access forms. If you like unbound forms, choose another tool like Visual Studio and Winforms.

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

Comment: I tried to bind the form to the table the past tow days. I have another database that I bound the form to the table on and it is working flawlessly. I literally did nothing, but changed the field names and adjusted the names accordingly in the code and I can't get it to run. Trust me I know what you;re saying Gustav and I tried, but I'm at my wits end with it.

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to answer this since there are too many points to cover.  Gustav already gave great advise about learning to use Access Forms like they are intended.  But from the screenshots, it looks like you misunderstand something fundamental about the Access query designer.  Even though you shouldn't have to write any queries for want you want to do, at some point you will need to understand how to properly design a query.

If you want the query to insert FROM the form INTO the table, then the table field references should not be in the criteria, they should be like this:

- Field: [Forms]![frmInventory]![ICN]
- Table: {leave blank}
- Append To: ICN
- Criteria: {leave blank}

Also, remove [tblInventoryTemp] from the query window since you already specified the destination table in the Append Query pop-up window.  The SQL should look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblInventoryTemp ( ICN, model, serial, ... )
SELECT [Forms]![tblInventory]![ICN], [Forms]![tblInventory]![model], [Forms]![tblInventory]![serial], ...
```

Likewise for the other query to copy from temp to the main table.  You should have already specified the destination table in the pop-up window, so remove [tblInventory] from the query window.  Also remove the list of fields you have in the Criteria row.  The SQL should look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblInventory ( manu, model, serial, ... )
SELECT tblInventoryTemp.manu, tblInventoryTemp.model, tblInventoryTemp.serial, ...
FROM tblInventoryTemp
```

Access will likely add more details, but the general form of the SQL should match what I have.

Comment: Yeah I tried what Gustav suggested two days ago, trust me. I have another database that was setup that way and it works flawlessly. Since this one is so similar, I figured copying it over and then just renaming the fields and appropriate names in the database would work, but unfortunately it's not and I have NO clue why, which is why I've devolved into trying to do this query nonsense.

Comment: It's difficult to respond to that, because we're all trying to give you clues.  I reviewed your previous 2 questions and it looks like you're trying to solve too many problems at once. You say that you tried what Gustav suggested and to "trust" you, but you stated yourself that you're new to this. From the screenshots and your frustration, no I don't trust that you are building the forms correctly... regardless of whether this approach worked before.  Although you responded to some comments, I don't see that you answered directly about debugging VBA and indicating precise error locations, etc.